# Memory optimization of empty varargs

Tags: java, optimization, variadic-functions

With this method:

```
    public void args(Class... methodArgsTypes) {
        if (methodArgsTypes.length == 0) {
            methodArgsTypes = NO_PARAMETERS;  // public static Class[0] array
        }
        this.methodArgsTypes = methodArgsTypes;
    }
```

when method is called with no arguments `args()`, the `Class[0]` is created. Since `methodArgsTypes` value is hold during the lifetime of the app (when you remove the `if` block above), would it make sense to have the `if` block as above? The purpose of it is to prevent creation of many empty arrays in the memory and keep reference to only one, public static empty array. Hence, less memory.

Would this make sense?

Comment: how many of these zero length arrays are created during the lifetime of the app?

Comment: It can be a lot. Most methods are without args, that are scanned in this use case.

Comment: Hard to tell the overall effect without benchmarking and measuring. Lucky for you, it's literally a three-line change --  why not just try it and see? Also, if you're invoking this really as a vararg (and not with an explicit `Class[]` that you pass to the vararg), you can create a simple overload that uses the NO_PARAMTERS const: `public void args() { args(NO_PARAMETERS); }`.

Answer (score 0):

No, because of 2 reasons:
1) an empty array is pretty small, and it will die almost instantly, so it won't have any significant impact on your memory behavior
2) the just-in-time compiler will most likely optimize it away anyway, due to its aggressive inlining optimizations.

Comment: Hm, 1) is not true, since it is assigned to a local variable stored in for the lifetime of the application (what happens if you remove the `if` block). For 2), do you know this for sure? How can I measure?

Comment: 1) is indeed true, because if you do not do your optimization, an array of 24 bytes on 64-bit machines will be allocated for every call, which dies when the method returns at the latest. And I think 24 bytes as long as the method is active can be tolerated! For 2), that is difficult, the optimization is called "escape analysis and scalar replacement" and is implemented in the current Hotspot JIT compiler. You can probably find out by looking at the tracing flags of the VM and try to find out if the method is indeed inlined.